# Function.length and variable (...rest) argument length [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to determine if a (anonymous) function has defined the ...(rest) parameter in ActionScript 3? I know there's the function.length property, but it only counts the explicitly defined arguments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ...rest, but you can access the arguments array like arguments[0] so if you know the length you can get the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean checking to see if the function has defined parameters when it was called, then the only way to really do this (to my knowledge) is to prototype the function class and then inside your newly prototyped function class, capture the args array parameter and check to see if it's null. I'm not going to figure out and write all that code for you (lack of time) but here is a nice article that should thoroughly describe this process and have you well on your way.

http://tobyho.com/Modifying_Core_Types_in_ActionScript_3_Using_the_Prototype_Object

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to determine if a function has defined a ...rest parameter, but you can only determine this within the function's body. Outside the function's body, the function has 0 parameters as shown by the first trace output. In reality, this ...rest parameter is an array that only has scope inside the body of the function. However, once you're inside the function body you can test for it, as shown by the second and third trace outputs.

```
    public function Test()
    {
        trace(doSomething.length);
        doSomething(7, 8, 9, 10);
    }

    public function doSomething(...numbers):void
    {
        if (numbers.length > 0) trace("Found the parameters!");
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) trace(numbers[i]);
    }

Output: 0    
Output: Found the parameters!    
Output: 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I was specifically looking for a way to detect this outside of the function, with some light reflection.